# Debugging Windows service on Remote Server in VS2019

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-services, console-application, remote-debugging

I have deployed some Windows services application on my server. but something wrong occur and i need to debug that windows services in my computer on VS2019. how i can do that.? please give some clue.
thanks

this is the application logs

Service is started at 11/18/2021 7:48:16 PM

Service is stopped at 11/18/2021 7:50:57 PM

Service is started at 11/18/2021 7:51:48 PM

Service is stopped at 11/18/2021 7:53:19 PM

Service is started at 11/18/2021 8:07:08 PM

Service is recall at : 11/18/2021 8:09:00 PM

Service is recall at : 11/18/2021 8:10:46 PM

Service is stopped at 11/18/2021 8:11:55 PM

Comment: Application Logs can help...

Comment: on application logs there is no suspicious . ok i will update my post

Comment: in Windows event viewer -> "eventvwr" - run command -> application logs .

Comment: that right.. i need to write into event viewer log to know what the result each function.. please wait i will add my code

Comment: @BhushanMuttha.. thank you based on your clue, i have known where the issue. actually on my code are fine. but i dont why, the .bat file cannot launch. my windows services is call the bat file to run Macro (some robotic software)

Comment: Is it resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @BhushanMuttha clue. i have figured out what the specific issue. and i have figured out to the solution. thanks for your help.

the issue is.. my Windows services application cannot start the bat file. so i just change my method from windows service to console application that can starting up when the OS start

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of ways. I suggest you go with the simplest method first. i.e. using `try catch` block.

Use multiple `try` catches as per the need of your code and in the `catch` block mention a **meaningful message** to know where exactly the exception was thrown and for what reason.

Comment: my code always in try catch block